# Fishy: VMware sends traffic through akamai

Tags: linux, macos

I'm running Linux inside of VMware on the Mac, and on the Linux guest, I'm running a program that has connections open to perhaps 4 different machines.

On the OS/X host, however, VMware has only 1 active network connection: To `a184-85-99-51.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com`. And what is also strange is that in my firewall settings I told it to block outgoing connections to that server, but these are being ignored. I also added a line in /etc/hosts to direct requests back to localhost, which is being ignored.

Could it be that VMware is recording all network traffic into & out of the VM using the Akamai server?

Comment: Which firewall settings? The host's?

Answer (score 2):

It would entirely depend on your setup. For instance if you are using a bridged connection then your firewall will be ignored

For the other part, without a tcp dump of the connection, we can't answer this question. Akamai is a content delivery network, they are often used to offload static content to anothe server as to increase performance.

Answer (score 1):

To confirm, I ran Wireshark on my Windows 10 Desktop, while opening and creating a VM in VMWare Workstation. Firewall disabled outgoing messages but enabled DNS.

I saw 2 packets in regards to Akamai Technologies @ 23.49.186.68

I disabled the update check in preferences.
I have yet to log any recorded traffic to Akamai since.

VMWare does not phone home without the CEIP (Customer Experience Improvement Program), which is offered during install.

Answer (score 0):

> On the OS/X host, however, VMware has only 1 active network connection

Whatever tool you are using to view network connections is probably only displaying the network connections used by the VMWare GUI, not by the actual virtual machine.

> And what is also strange is that in my firewall settings I told it to block outgoing connections to that server, but these are being ignored.

Impossible to say for sure what's going on here, but my best guess would be that you didn't configure the firewall correctly.

> I also added a line in `/etc/hosts` to direct requests back to localhost, which is being ignored.

The VMWare GUI is almost certainly using a different hostname for that CDN server. `/etc/hosts` only affects name resolution; it is not a firewall, and cannot be used to block all connections to an IP address.

> Could it be that VMware is recording all network traffic into & out of the VM using the Akamai server?

Highly unlikely.